# Unable to get Sprite maps to work correctly in THREE js

Tags: javascript, three.js, sprite

I am simply trying to add a sprite to my scene normally. I am using this image: i.imgur.com/kMT4mOH.png

```
var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('i.imgur.com/kMT4mOH.png');
var mat = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map:map, color: 0xff5200, fog: true, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending});
var glow = new THREE.Sprite(mat);
scene.add(glow);
```

However when I add color to the sprite, the entire image turns the color instead of just the white space.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/2331/

Im not entirely sure what Im doing wrong and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The image is not loading properly

Comment: @2pha Any insight on how to make it load properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is not loading because the url to the image is `i.imgur.com/kMT4mOH.png`. So the page is searching for the file on locally. ie. `http://fiddle.jshell.net/VsWb9/2331/show/i.imgur.com/kMT4mOH.png`.

To get the file from its external location you would use `http://i.imgur.com/kMT4mOH.png`, but you then get the problem of cross domain restrictions on webgl textures, so this will also not work also.

I don't see any problem with your code so if you run it from a server where the texture image and the image file are both on the same server, it should work.

Read more about cross domain webgl images at: http://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html

There seems there may be a work around if you really need it to work in a jsfiddle, it is outlined on this other stackoverflow question: [cross-domain image for three.js (canvas/webGL), proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710414/cross-domain-image-for-three-js-canvas-webgl-proxy)